# unserializ not working for large text

Tags: php, serialization

I have a class that contains a large text field that will contain text that could be a contract or business form, Here is my code so far:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if (isset ($_POST['Save']) && $this->isPostSafe()) {
        $form = Form::getPostObject();
        $form->text = addslashes($form->text);
        var_dump($form);
        $form->save($this->_databaseConnection);
    }
    $this->redirect('/forms');
}

public function __construct()
{
    $company_info = Config::get('Company');
    foreach ($company_info as $setting => $value) {
        $this->variables[$setting] = $value;
    }
    $this->variables = serialize($this->variables);
}

public function set($name, $value)
{
    $values = unserialize($this->variables);
    $values[$name] = $value;
    $this->variables = serialize($this->variables);
}

public function render()
{
    var_dump($this->variables);
    $values = unserialize($this->variables);

    foreach ( $values as $key => $value) {
        $from = "[@$key]";
        $this->text = str_replace($from, $value, $this->text);
    }
    return $template;
}
```

The problem is the var_dump gives me the unserialized string and I have tried base64_encode and it did not solve the problem

Comment: your problem doesn't make sense, please be more clear

Comment: What do I need to add? I am not getting an array back. I am getting the same unserialized string

Comment: this line `$this->variables = serialize($this->variables);` in set should probably be `$this->variables = serialize($values);`

Comment: maybe you want to var dump $values 2 lines down in render, thats when you unserialize

Comment: it would make sense to only call serialize on save and unserialize on load instead of every time a property is accessed

Comment: @Orangepill Thank you, please post an answer so I can tag it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set function is wrong

```
public function set($name, $value)
{
    $values = unserialize($this->variables);
    $values[$name] = $value;
    $this->variables = serialize($this->variables);
}
```

should be

```
public function set($name, $value)
{
    $values = unserialize($this->variables);
    $values[$name] = $value;
    $this->variables = serialize($values);
}
```

Comment: guess i was too slow :)

Comment: @Orangepill You have a big lead :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is for a rewrite of the code... basically you only want to deal with serialization when an object is saved and deserialization when an object is loaded

```
public function __construct()
{
    $company_info = Config::get('Company');
    foreach ($company_info as $setting => $value) {
        $this->variables[$setting] = $value;
    }
}

public function set($name, $value)
{
      $this->variables[$name] = $value;
}

public function get($name){
      return isset($this->variables[$name])?$this->variables[$name]:"";
}

public function render()
{
    // for debugging
    var_dump($this->variables);

    foreach ( $this->variabes as $key => $value) {
        $from = "[@$key]";
        $this->text = str_replace($from, $value, $this->text);
    }
    return $template;
}

public function saveAction()
{
    if (isset ($_POST['Save']) && $this->isPostSafe()) {
        $form = Form::getPostObject();
        $form->text = addslashes($form->text);
        var_dump($form);
        $serialized = serialize($this->variables); // serialize before you save
        $form->save($this->_databaseConnection);
    }
    $this->redirect('/forms');
}
```